# Codimension of $\ker $ $\alpha $

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

> Can someone explain why the codimension of $\ker $ $\alpha $ is $1$ in $ H $, with complement $ Fh_\alpha $?

Is this because $ h_\alpha $ when $ \alpha $ is simple is part of the dual basis to the root space $ H^*$?

Where:
$ H $ is the Cartan of a Lie algebra $ L $ (I don't know if it has to be semisimple)

$\alpha $ is a root not necessarily simple

$ h_\alpha=[{x_\alpha}{y_\alpha}]$ for $ x_\alpha $ $\in L_\alpha $ and $ y_\alpha$ $\in L_{-\alpha} $.

And $ F $ is the base field.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a linear map from $H$ to $F$ which is not $0$.

Comment: I know, but in Humphreys' book he said, in his proof that $+\alpha $ and $-\alpha $ are the only root multiples of $ \alpha $, that $ ker $ $\alpha $ has codimension $1$ in $ H $ with complement $ Fh_\alpha $ where $ h_\alpha=[{x_\alpha}{y_\alpha}]$.

Comment: That it has codimension $1$ follows simply from what I stated. What the complement is follows from the definition of $h_{\alpha}$ (I think you need $L$ to be semisimple to get $h_{\alpha}$).